# The expected value of the sum of Poisson distribution sample series with upper bound on the sampled value

Tags: probability-theory, poisson-distribution

I am trying to give a theoretical background for a sample process.

I am sampling values from a Poisson process with a fixed $\lambda$.
I am trying to calculate the expected value of $n$ samples from Poisson distribution when considering only the maximal value between the random value and $\lambda$.

Consider the following function:

$$
C(x)=
\begin{cases}
x, & x \le \lambda\\
\lambda, & x > \lambda\\
\end{cases}
$$

I am trying to calculate the expected value of: $\sum_{i=0}^{n}C(X)$

My first attempt was to try and calculate $\mathbb{P}(X \le \lambda)$:

$\mathbb{P}(X \le \lambda) = e^{-\lambda}\sum_{i=0}^{\lambda}\frac{\lambda^{i}}{i!}$

But I am not sure how to proceed from here. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One might note that
$$
x\mathbb{P}(X=x)=\lambda \mathbb{P}(X=x-1)
$$
and therefore,

$$
\mathbb{E}\mathbb{1}_{X< \lambda}X=\sum_{i=1}^{\lceil \lambda-1\rceil} i\mathbb{P}(X=i)=\lambda \sum_{j=0}^{\lceil\lambda-2\rceil} \mathbb{P}(X=j)=\lambda\mathbb{P}(X\leq \lambda-2),
$$
which, in turn, gives
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}C(X)&=\mathbb{E}\mathbb{1}_{X< \lambda}X+\mathbb{E}1_{X\geq\lambda}\lambda\\
&=\lambda \mathbb{P}(X\leq \lambda-2)+\lambda \mathbb{P}(X\geq \lambda)\\
&=\lambda(1-\mathbb{P}(X\in (\lambda-2,\lambda)))
\end{align}
Now, there's exactly one natural number in $(\lambda-2,\lambda)$, call it $\lambda^*$ and thus,
$$
\mathbb{E}C(X)=\lambda\left(1-e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^{\lambda^*}}{\lambda^*!}\right)
$$

Comment: I think that the first equation is wrong. Shouldn't it be: $x\mathbb{P}(X=x)=\lambda e ^{-1}
\mathbb{P}(X=x-1)$ ?

Comment: $\frac{\mathbb{P}(X=x)}{\mathbb{P}(X=x-1)}=\frac{e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^x}{x!}}{e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^{x-1}}{(x-1)!}}=\frac{\lambda}{x}$